# Cannot deploy or update autonumber field

Tags: custom-field, setup, auto-number

I just hit a very strange issue when trying to deploy my sources today.
We have an autonumber field on Lead (format: {YYYY}-{0000000000}; starting number: 1000), that already exists in my sandbox. But when I try to push this field (with or without the reste of the sources) to my sandbox from VS Code, it fails with following error message :
"**INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY: invalid cross reference id**".

Even weirder, if I go to setup and try to modify the field (without changing anything), I get the following error message :
"**Data Not Available - You do not have Edit access to one of the two records you are trying to merge. Please contact your administrator to get additional access or merge the two records**".

Not sure what is going on here...
I have full access on the field (SysAdmin profil + FLS ok) and the field definition update triggers a merge issue!

Have anyone encountered this before?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I also have encountered the same issue in every sandbox (4) I created today

Anything I try to update in setup/object manager gives the `Data Not Available - You do not have Edit access to one of the two records you are trying to merge [...]` error, and trying to create or delete components through sfdx or the dev console result in the same `INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY: invalid cross reference id` error. Heck, even trying to create a new empty class gives this error

Checking the browser logs, the server returned a 500 status (Internal Server Error) every time, so it seems a problem on Salesforce's end. The best we can do now is open a support case and cross our fingers.

Comment: I see the 500 status in the logs, but I don't see this issue on every field... Case opened with Salesforce on my end as weel!

Comment: Hi All - just to let you know that it was an interim issue from Salesforce end. I was also facing the same issue since 21st Feb Monday so I raised a Salesforce Case where the support person has confirmed today that the resolution has been provided by them and it should work fine. For me it is working fine now. Please try to check from your end once more - hopefully it should have resolved by now.

Answer (score 0):

It was a Salesforce platform bug, happening randomly on metadata creation or update. Salesforce support has solved it, but no idea what was going on.